# How to refer to a variable called frame while in pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

In Rails, when I'm using pry, how do I refer to a variable called `frame`, as opposed to calling the `frame` command?

I'm using Rails 4.1.x, pry 0.10.3, pry-alias 0.0.1, pry-byebug 3.3.0, and pry-rails 0.3.4.

Comment: `frame` should automatically refer to a `frame` variable that's in scope. You shouldn't need to do anything special. `frame = 3; binding.pry` shows me `3` when I type `frame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to pry documentation: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Command-system#Invoking_commands, you need to prefix the ruby code with a semicolon, so pry wouldn't interpret it as a command, like `;frame`